# SVNKit or JavaHL in Ubuntu 64 bits

Tags: eclipse, svn, svnkit, javahl

what better SVNKit or JavaHL

Eclipse

Subversive or Subclipse?

Whenever I install the Eclipse again have this doubt has differences in terms of one being better than another, etc ...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It comes down to a matter of taste:

- SVNKit is a total rewrite of SVN in Java. So if you use this connector, you are "pure" java running.
- JavaHL on the other side is a native binding of the original C libraries, so you are calling the compiled C+Code via JNI

At the moment both libraries support SVN 1.7, but SVNKit had a lot of trouble to release a full SVN 1.7 client (due to SVN working copy modifications in 1.7)

So if there is a new version of SVN, JavaHL is often earlier available. But most of the time a bit more hassle to install, because it has to be binary compatible to your svn installation(if you do not know what "binary compatible" means, use SVNKit)[thanks to centic for his comment!]

But in the end both backends are **fully compatible** with svn. JavaHL is basically SVN and SVNKit performs all SVN tests with correct results

Comment: I would add that JavaHL can cause problems if the native libraries are not correctly installed or if the bit-ness (32/64 bit) does not match.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Subclipse (tigris) as I always encountered synch problem with Subversive SVN like:

- Refresh the SVN Sync View;
- Some commited files stays in the sync view
- Sometime some files stays uncommitted even I commit a whole folder.

These side-effects occurs both in Eclipse Indigo under Windows 7 and under RedHat (RHEL6.2).

With Subclipse (tigris) it was always perfect (I was under Win7, my colleagues under Ubuntu and MacOS X).